# How to make IntelliSense autocomplete always *auto* popup without hotkey?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, intellisense

~as I'm using a Surface without hardware keyboard, always wanna kill myself as I'm typing long field/parameter names.

(Specially for F#)

Comment: No idea with F#, but with C# with any key press the intellisense autocomplete is shown by default, no need to press any hotkey.

Comment: Have you check the issues on GitHub?

Comment: Well, yes, I see it's auto popup for C#, but only after I press "." or CTRL+J in F#.

Comment: Did you already try *Ctrl + Alt + Space* or "Edit" -> "IntelliSense" -> "Toggle Completion Mode"?

Comment: That's grayed out... Unable to select. ="( @Filburt

Comment: Looks like F# behaves different there.

Comment: Yep~ Maybe~ @Filburt